# How to synchronize data between several copies of a VMWare instance?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, synchronization

I have multiple copies of a VMWare virtual machine that is running Ubuntu 10.04 Server that I am using for development (web and compiled applications).  I would like to keep all of these copies synchronized.  Specifically, I need to keep the following items the same across all the machines:

- Packages
- Config files
- Data files in /home/ directory

I using Git for the source code, so I don't have to worry about that, just the system files.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For packages and config files looks like you're looking for a config management system, such as cfengine or puppet. See the wikipedia for a [comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software) .

To replicate /home , you might want to try Unison or rsync.